# Diophantine power equation of degree 4 and 5 and 2 variables

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Prove that $a^4 + 1 = 2b^4$ and $a^4 - 1 = 2b^4$ have no solutions in integers. Same with $a^5$ and $b^5$.

Comment: Are $0$ and $1$ no longer considered integers?

Comment: You might get better answers if you were to show what you have tried, or at least give some background about where this question originated (that helps to determine which tools might be available to answer the question).

Comment: Perhaps you meant: "Prove that neither $a^4 + 1 = 2b^4$ nor $a^4 - 1 = 2b^4$ have solutions in integers greater than $1$."

Comment: For the first one, see my answer here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/24609/are-there-primes-p-q-such-that-p41-2q2/24636#24636

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This addresses the equation $a^4-1=2b^4$. Note we may assume $a,b \ge 0$ since changing their signs has no effect, and sign possibilities may be noted afterwards. Now note that $a$ must be odd and write $a=2t+1$ where $t \ge 0$ is an integer. Then the equation in terms of $t$, on factoring $a^4-1$ and dividing by 2,  becomes
$$4t(t+1)(2t^2+2t+1)=b^4.$$

Now we see $b$ is even and so we can put $b=2s$, so $b^4=16s^4$, and we arrive at
$$[1] \ \ t(t+1)(2t^2+2t+1)=4s^4.$$
The three factors on the left are pairwise coprime. That $\gcd(t,t+1)=1$ and $\gcd(t,2t^2+2t+1)=1$ is immediate, and if a prime $p$ were to divide both $t+1$ and $2t^2+2t+1$, then $p$ would also divide $(t+1)^2=t^2+2t+1$, and hence also divide the difference $(2t^2+2t+1)-(t^2+2t+1)=t^2.$ but then $p$ divides both $t+1$ and $t$, impossible.

So equation [1] is a product of three pairwise coprime factors equal to the square $(2s^2)^2$. Therefore all three factors are squares. But the only way both $t$ and $t+1$ are square is if $t=0$, leading to the solution $(a,b)=(1,0)$, where we can also include $(a,b)=(-1,0)$ on changing sign. These are then the only integer solutions to $a^4-1=2b^4$. The same argument works for the more inclusive equation $a^4-1=2b^2$, by the way.
The other equation $a^4+1=2b^4$ has not such a simple solution, at least that I can see.

Comment: Thanks  coffeemath. Hope somebody will find a not too hard way to solve a^4 +1 = 2b^4

Comment: Thank you Byron. It would be of some interest if considering now the general equation a^2n +1 = 2b^2n; if the method could be extended to prove  no solutions  to z^2 = ((a^2n -1)/2)^2 = b^4n -a^2n.

Answer (score 1):

$$a^4+1=2b^4\,\,,\,\,a^4-1=2b^4\Longrightarrow a^4+1=a^4-1$$

and the last equation has no solution in any field (ring) of characteristic different from $\,2\,$ , let alone in the integers.

Comment: I think it should be proved that neither the first nor the second equation has a solution in integers except (1,0)

Comment: As written, it looks like a system of two equations, which as proved has no solution. If the OP wanted the equations separatedly he could have used "neither" or "each" or something like that, imo.

Comment: Although the grammar may not be correct, I don't think that the intended question was "Prove that $a^4+1=2b^4$ and $a^4-1=2b^4$ do not have simultaneous solutions". I think it is clear that the OP intended "Prove that neither $a^4 + 1 = 2b^4$ nor $a^4 - 1 = 2b^4$ have solutions in integers." Just as people whose native language is not English struggle to post questions in English, we should make some effort to understand their questions, even if their translation is not quite right.

Comment: Well, I'm not a native english speaker and, in fact, english is just my third language (it shows, uh?), so I may have not understood the actual intention of the OP...Yet he hasn't still said a word about anything after posting his question.

Comment: It's only been a couple of hours. Perhaps the OP did not expect such a quick response. There are probably good reasons that one might not be able to attend to their account for a few hours. I like to give the benefit of the doubt, especially to new users.

Comment: So do I like to give that benefit. I was only saying so that I shall wait for him to explain himself.

Comment: Thanks for the feed back. I am not a native english speaking guy, but a Spaniard living in Spain. I learnt english when i was in high school. Am 58 years old now, so this i not homework. They are not two simultanous equations but 2 different equations; 4 different equations if we consider the exponent to be 5.

Comment: Thanks for the feed back. I am not a native english speaking guy, but a Spaniard living in Spain. I learnt english when i was in high school. Am 58 years old now, so this i not homework. They are not two simultanous equations but 2 different equations; 4 different equations if we consider the exponent to be 5.The problem arises when i tried as an amateur to prove binomial coefficients C(n,k) cannot be a 4-th power for k=2.That is C(a^4,2)=a^4(a^4-1)/2=b^4 if a^4-1=2b^4 and C(a^4+1,2)=b^4 if a^4+1=2b^4.

Comment: Sorry;The problem arises when i tried as an amateur to prove binomial coefficients C(n,k) cannot be a 4-th power for k=2.That is C(a^4,2)=a^4(a^4-1)/2=c^4 if a^4-1=2b^4 and C(a^4+1,2)=c^4 if a^4+1=2b^4. 
Euler proved the case where the exponent is 3 and i was wondering if the case of 4 and 5 exponents would be too difficult to solve. Paul Erdös proved C(n,k) is never x^l (l>1); but it was only a partial proof , for k>3.

Comment: A difficult  proof in my opinion, i did not understand it ,from Paul Erdös that binomial coefficients C(n,k) are not a power x^l for k>3.The proof is uncomplete. I would like to know if somebody could prove it for k=2 and k=3. http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1951-05.pdf